# MATLAB. Inverse crop images. 

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I would like to crop an image but I want to retain the part of image that is `outside` of the rectangle. How can this can be done?
It seems that with imcrop only the part within the rectangle can be retained.

Comment: Sigh. When you crop an image, you throw that part away! If you don't want that, then don't crop it!!!!!!!!!! Or, if you insist on retaining that information, then you will need to do the crop yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An image in Matlab is represented by a matrix, just like any other matrix, you can read more about representation forms [here](http://www.eng.auburn.edu/~reevesj/Classes/IP/IP.html).

It seems that what you want to do is to take the area that you don't want and change the values of the corresponding cells in the matrix to the color that you want to put instead (each cell in the matrix is a pixel in the image). That is if you know the place where your unwanted data is.

If you don't know where it is, and want to use the tool given by `imcrop` to manually choose the "cropped" area, you can take the resulting matrix, and find the part of the original image which is an exact match with the cropped part, and to color it as you wish.

The code for doing this:

```
I=imread('img_9.tif');
I2=imcrop(I,[60,50,85,85]);
n_big=size(I);
n_small=size(I2);

for j1=1:(n_big(1)-n_small(1))
for j2=1:(n_big(2)-n_small(2))
    Itest=I(j1:j1+n_small(1)-1,j2:j2+n_small(2)-1,:);
    if ( Itest == I2)
        I(j1:j1+n_small(1)-1,j2:j2+n_small(2)-1,:) = zeros(n_small(1),n_small(2),3);
    end
end
end

figure(1);
imshow(I);
figure(2);
imshow(I2);
```

The results of my test were:

original:

[image: original image]

cropped:

[image: cropped image]

resulting image:

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

maybe what you want to do is first a mask with the inverse area of what you want to crop and save this result.