# Inverse imcrop() function in matlab? (selecting outside of the box, not inside)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, crop

I want to use imcrop function or any other way to extract outside part of the bounding box in matlab. for example original image size is 128*128 and I want to extract outside values of the following bounding box : [15, 32, 95,23]. for instance, bounding box represents the eyes and I want other parts of the face except eyes.
Please take a look at the image for better clarification.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPhtC.jpg)

Comment: Try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892295/matlab-inverse-crop-images

Comment: I think you can simply place 255 in the selected area. Something like: `I(32:32+23, 15:15+95, :) = 255;`